# Oracle(11g) strange xquery behaviour

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xquery

i've a very strange xquery problem. I loop over a big xml with round about 80000 node values:

```
     insert
    into xxif_vendor_onhand_interface (
         vendor_onhand_interface_id
        ,created_by
        ,creation_date
        ,last_updated_by
        ,last_update_date
        ,status_code
        ,vendor_site_id
        ,org_id
        ,inventory_item_id
        ,vendor_item_number
        ,vendor_onhand_quantity)
  select xxif_vendor_onhand_interface_s.nextval
        ,fnd_global.user_id
        ,sysdate
        ,fnd_global.user_id
        ,sysdate
        ,'NEW'
        ,vs.vendor_site_id
        ,vs.org_id
        ,asl.item_id
        ,asl.primary_vendor_item
        ,x.oh_qty
    from xxpo_vendor_site_attributes   vsa
        ,po_vendor_sites_all           vs
        ,xmltable(
         'for $i in /TBSTOCK/ARTICLE return $i'
         passing l_xml
         columns "TB_SKU" varchar2(50) path '/ARTICLE/A_NR'
                ,"OH_QTY" number path '/ARTICLE/A_STOCK'
         ) x
        ,po_approved_supplier_list     asl
   where vsa.attribute_name            = '???'
     and vsa.attribute_value           = 'Y'                
     and vs.vendor_site_id             = vsa.vendor_site_id;
```

I expect the same amount in the result but only the last 10.000 values are in the result.

I have ensured that with this code:

```
  --onhand logging
  BEGIN
     v_history_s := xxif_tb_onhand_history_s.NEXTVAL;

     INSERT INTO xxif_tb_oh_history_headers (xxif_tb_onhand_history_id,
                                             onhand_xml,
                                             created_by,
                                             creation_date,
                                             last_updated_by,
                                             last_update_date,
                                             last_update_login)
          VALUES (v_history_s,
                  l_xml,
                  NVL (fnd_global.user_id, -1),
                  SYSDATE,
                  NVL (fnd_global.user_id, -1),
                  SYSDATE,
                  NVL (fnd_global.login_id, -1));


     FOR r
        IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '/ARTICLE/A_NR') AS a_nr,
                   EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '/ARTICLE/A_STOCK') AS a_stock
              FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (l_xml, '/TBSTOCK/ARTICLE'))) p)
     LOOP
        INSERT INTO xxif_tb_oh_history_lines (xxif_tb_onhand_history_id,
                                              a_nr,
                                              a_stock,
                                              created_by,
                                              creation_date,
                                              last_updated_by,
                                              last_update_date,
                                              last_update_login)
             VALUES (v_history_s,
                     r.a_nr,
                     r.a_stock,
                     NVL (fnd_global.user_id, -1),
                     SYSDATE,
                     NVL (fnd_global.user_id, -1),
                     SYSDATE,
                     NVL (fnd_global.login_id, -1));
     END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
        NULL;
  END;
```

It seems that data will be overwritten after 10.000 records. I don't know where  the problem is. Only the last 9.000 values from the xml are in the table.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Tim

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and  mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Hy guys,
i solved it by my own.

1. I've fetch the xmltype variable in a clob

l_oh_clob := l_xml.getClobVal();

2. convert clob to xmltype

xmltable(
 'for $i in /TBSTOCK/ARTICLE return $i'
 passing xmltype(l_oh_clob)
 columns "TB_SKU" varchar2(50) path '/ARTICLE/A_NR'
        ,"OH_QTY" number path '/ARTICLE/A_STOCK'
 ) x
,po_approved_supplier_list     asl;

not pretty but it works!

Tim